# Not able to open palette in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported android project I wanted to modify, that its not showing palette option,and also after importing its showing wrong path and I am not able to change path. I tried using `manifest.xml` file, but not able to build project as well.

Any help?

Comment: post your android studio error log

Comment: you want desing palette in .xml file ?